# Phalcon: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, model-view-controller, phalcon

How to pass to phalcon that some of columns are of type integer and empty values should be NULL not empty strings for them?

When I write `'emptyValue' => (int) Null` in Form then it passes 0 to database ...

Comment: Is default value in table column set to `NULL`?

Comment: Yes, it's default behaviour in postgres when there is no "NOT NULL" declaration.